# Can I use the PayPal API to transfer money from one PayPal account to another without paying a fee?

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I'd like to find a cheaper (free) service to use to transfer money between my websites customers and [Stripe's](https://stripe.com/) fees a very high.

I can't seem to get any clear answer from the PayPal website for developers or by talking with a customer service reps on the phone.

In my website, I want to transfer money (via API) from my customers account (PayPal) to my business account (PayPal), then at a later time, transfer money from my business account to another customer account (PayPal).

Can this be done NO transaction fee?
If no, what are the transaction fees for this, I'm a little confused by the fee site.

Is this is the correct page? - https://developer.paypal.com/docs/payouts/reference/fees/

Or do I look under the merchant fees and which link? - https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/mpp/merchant-fees#paypal-payouts

I also see adaptive payments, but it says on the site that it isn't available for "new integrations". Does this mean I can start using it when I go live with my site?
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/archive/adaptive-payments/

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not really a programming or computer-related question.

Comment: There are many other questions like this on SO. So please don't vote to close it

Comment: This forum isn't Paypal support. Only Paypal can give you the correct answer. It looks like you've found a possible answer in url #2. It seems to depend on a variety of factors such as payment type, location, etc. Url #3 says "Deprecated".

Answer (score 0):

> API...without paying a fee

No, the usual processing fees apply to all API transactions.

The only PayPal transfers without a fee are in certain countries that have payments to "friends & family", which are not for business or commercial purposes and can be initiated only [in paypal.com](https://www.paypal.com/myaccount/transfer/homepage/pay) and sourced from the PayPal balance or local bank (sending money from a card always has a fee).

---

Regarding fee types, merchant fees apply to receiving payments to your account and payouts fees apply to sending money from your account (if you have the payouts service)

Comment: Hi Preston. Do you know of any service that will transfer money around without any fee or a lower fee than Stripe/PayPal? I read a while back that Venmo used to allow you to transfer around money between Venmo accounts without any fee, but they ended this type of account processing a while back.